# Keep only first two digits after decimal with no rounding

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i would like to keep only first two digits after decimal but i don't want to round or convert the value.

For example:

```
143,655 -> 143.65
547934,945 -> 547934,94
```

Converting or rounding the values doesn't work, it modifies the values.

Comment: That was `Comma` or `Dot`?

Answer (score 5):

use the `ROUND()` with truncate function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql

```
select  round(143.655, 2, 1),
        round(547934.945, 2, 1)
```

the last parameter, when non-zero, it will truncate

Comment: Solved, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dorian Stefan Please accept this answer if it solves your issue.